# QPrinter and QPainter print from TreeView to PDF error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtreeview

I'm trying to export data from QTreeView to PDF... 
How can I print all the data from QTreeview into one pdf file?

this is the code I tried with:

```
def printToPDF(self):
    fn,_ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,'Export PDF',None,'PDF files(.pdf);;All Files()')

    if fn !='':
        if QFileInfo(fn).suffix()=='': fn +='.pdf'
        printer= QPrinter(QPrinter.HighResolution)
        printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)

        printer.setOutputFileName(fn)
        painter = QPainter()
        painter.begin(printer)
        try:
            self.treeView.render(painter)
        finally:
            painter.end()
```

I managed to make a pdf file with him but nothing else.
I only get the part that can be seen without moving the scroll and that part has been reduced

[image]

How to solve this? Thanks

EDIT:

```
class Stampaj_sve(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Stampaj_sve, self).__init__(parent)

        # dodjeljuje tri vjuv prethodno definisanom okviru
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        # kreira liniju za unos teksta za pretragu

        self.btn_stampaj=QPushButton()
        self.btn_stampaj.setText('Export to PDF')
        self.btn_stampaj.clicked.connect(self.printToPDF)

        self.tableView = QTreeView()


        # dodjeljuje okviru self.tableView
        lay.addWidget(self.btn_stampaj)
        lay.addWidget(self.tableView)

        # pravi promjenjivu za pretragu baze podataka
        self.model = QtSql.QSqlQueryModel()
        self.model.setQuery("SELECT Lokacija,Kancelarija,Prezime,Ime,Telefon,Lokal,Fax,Oblast FROM telImenik")
        # upisuje rezultate pretrage baze u self.tableView

        self.tableView.setModel(self.model)

        # odredjuje sirinu kolona u self.tableView-u prva kolona je 0-nulta,id nema potrebe dodavati jer ga sam odredjuje
        for i, width in enumerate([150, 65, 100, 80, 90, 40, 80, 340]):
            self.tableView.setColumnWidth(i, width)

    def printToPDF(self):
        fn, _ = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 'Export PDF', None, 'PDF files(.pdf);;All Files()')

        if fn != '':
            if QFileInfo(fn).suffix() == '': fn += '.pdf'
            printer = QPrinter(QPrinter.HighResolution)
            printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter.PdfFormat)

            printer.setOutputFileName(fn)
            painter = QPainter()
            painter.begin(printer)
            try:
                self.tableView.render(painter)
            finally:
                painter.end()
```

I want all lines from QTreeview to be displayed in one pdf file. I have 126 rows.

Comment: please show your Model.

Comment: Do you want to only enlarge the drawing or do you also want to show the hidden elements? if it is the latter, it could happen that the number of rows can be large, how do you want all the rows that do not fit on a sheet to be shown?

Comment: please answer my questions and you could also share your .db to be able to reproduce your problem easily, and thus focus on the problem.

Comment: Of its edition it indicates 126 rows, obviously in a page it is not going to enter everything. Do you want a pdf of several pages or only one?

Comment: On several pages, it's important for me to show everything,It does not matter how many pages I get in pdf!

Comment: Okay, great, now your question is clearer, you could share your .db to be able to reproduce your problem

Comment: And one more question: why do you use QTreeView when a typical QSqlQueryModel provides a table-type model using a QTableView?

Comment: I do not have any special reasons, I used QTableVIew in many places so do not be bored, every time the same look : D

Comment: Then use QTableView, is not there a problem?. On the other hand I probably will not get the same drawing as the view since my strategy is about to draw with html

Comment: it's not a problem, you know better than me how to properly do it.

Comment: Do you have any progress?